# Error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, mariadb

Codigo que trato de ejecutar.

```
MariaDB [hotel]> INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
    -> ('H01','CT01',01,2,1,1200,'sencilla');
```

Error que obtengo.

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`hotel`.`habitacion`, CONSTRAINT `habitacion_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`Id_cli`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`Id_cli`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) MariaDB [hotel]>

Mi problema es que al crear una base de datos y en la tabla habitación me surge un error y es el error 1452, he hecho la base varias veces viendo cual puede ser error, he cambiado cosas pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error al insertar datos en alguna tabla en este caso es la de habitación al agregar datos, quien pueda ayudarme le agradezco su ayuda.
Este es el código//

```
Create database hotel;


use hotel;



create table recepcionista(Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
 Nombre_re varchar(20) not null,
 A_pre varchar(30) not null,
 A_mre varchar(30) not null,
 telefono varchar(15) not null,
primary key(Clav_re));




INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT01','Juan','Osorio','Perez',914456435);



create table cliente(Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
Nombre_cli varchar(25) not null,
A_pcli varchar(25) not null,
A_mcli varchar(25) not null,
Telefono_cli varchar(15) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli),
index(Clav_re),
FOREIGN KEY(Clav_re)
REFERENCES recepcionista(Clav_re)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT02','RT01','Lalo','Perez','Perez',914456435);







 create table servicio (
Id_ser varchar(10) not null,
Tipo_ser varchar(25) not null,
Fecha date not null,
primary key(Id_ser));


INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST03','servicio3','2000-10-22');



create table cliSer (
Id_cli varchar(10),
Id_ser varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli,Id_ser),
INDEX (Id_cli),
INDEX(Id_ser),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli) REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Id_ser) REFERENCES servicio(Id_ser)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES
('CT02','ST03');
('CT01','ST01'),
('CT01','ST02');



create table habitacion (
Id_hab varchar(10) not null,
Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Num_hab int(10) not null,
Num_piso int(10) not null,
Dias int(10) not null,
Precio int(10) not null,
Tip_hab varchar(20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_hab),
index(Id_cli),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli)
REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);



INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H01','CT01',01,2,1,1200,'sencilla');
```

Comment: Reproduje tu código y es funcional

Comment: Disculpame no te entendi , soy nueva en esto de base de datos

Comment: Que probé el código que publicas y no marca error alguno

Comment: Ah ya muchas gracias por explicarme tomare una captura para mostrarles

Comment: Hola creo ya saber cual es tu error

Comment: Si cual ?, y les agradezco de verdad mucho su tiempo y apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se encuentra aqui en esta linea

```
INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H01','CT01',01,2,1,1200,'sencilla');
```

Si nos fijamos el campo dos

> Id_cli

es el ID del cliente, pero en el script que nos pones el unico cliente que insertas es este.

```
INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT02','RT01','Lalo','Perez','Perez',914456435);
```

Si nos damos cuenta su llave es CT02 y tu estas tratando de insertar el CT01 el cual no existe es por eso que te marca un error de llave, por que no hay alguna llave con ese dato que tratas de poner si en cambio pones.

```
INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H01','CT02',01,2,1,1200,'sencilla');
```

Podrás ver como se inserta.

Espero sea eso.

Saludos y espero tus comentarios.

Comment: Si es correcto ese era el error ya me dejó insertar los datos y no me marca error, de verdad muchas gracias por su apoyo y gracias por su tiempo, espero contar proximamente con su ayuda y conocimientos ya que yo apenas soy aprendiz, y agradezco su intencion de ayudar, Dios lo bendiga,  bendiciones

Comment: Si la respuesta fue correcta no olvides marcarla como correcta dandole click en el "tilde" que está debajo de lo flechas con el número de votos Saludos

Comment: Si claro, solo que no se donde marcarla

Comment: @Aurora Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Si muchas gracias por la recomendacion

Answer (score 1):

1. Deberías revisar tu tabla cliSer, según por lo que veo estas creando los 2 campos con Primary Key(ojo cuando esta en primary key no se puede repetir el mismo ID) y no entiendo porque las pusiste en primary key si son campos Foráneos quedaría así.

Código

```
create table cliSer (
Id_cli varchar(10),
Id_ser varchar(10),
INDEX (Id_cli),
INDEX(Id_ser),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli) REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Id_ser) REFERENCES servicio(Id_ser)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

2.Y si vas a insertar campos deberías verificar primero que los "ID" Ingresados existan ya están relacionadas las tablas, si 1 ID no existe te saldra error.

3.Y recuerda cada vez que quieras ingresar varios datos cámbiale el ; por , ya que el ";" nos indica que la consulta ya termino.

```
INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES
('CT02','ST03'),
('CT01','ST01'),
('CT01','ST02');
```

Comment: Ah ya entiendo, estaré revisando esos detalles, muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo.